# Number of isomorphisms between two graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

[image]

I'm studying for an exam in graph theory, and this question came up. The question is: how many isomorphisms exist between these two graphs. I know that, as they are isomorphic, this is the same as answering how many isomorphisms there are from the graph to itself.

I think the answer is $6$ or $3$, but I'm struggling to prove/show why this is correct/incorrect. Is there an easy way to see what the correct answer is, without explicitly writing down all the possible bijections?

Thanks

edit: I've included the graphs as a link now.

Comment: You did not seem to include the graph. Edit your post to include a link or image?

Comment: Where are you getting your values from? I'm not an expert, but I only see $4$ isomorphisms.

Comment: As i said it was only a first guess. 4 also makes sense. f(a) -> b', f(a)->c', f(a)-> e' and f(a)  -> f' ?

Comment: Right, that's the basic idea; any isomorphism will preserve the degrees of each vertex. This leaves 2 choices of how to map $b$ and $e$. Then, once you determine where $a$ is mapped to, everything else is locked in place.$.

Comment: Yeah sorry, i typed b and pressed enter before changing it, I've edited the comment to what I was trying to say now.

Comment: The comment still has some errors in it. You have mapped $a$ to three different vertices (so you aren't even a function), and you are skipping ahead too fast. For now, just focus on the vertex $b$. What are the only valid places you can map $b$ to?

Comment: I know, I was just trying to show the 4 different bijections, and what "a" would map to in those 4 bijections , the other mappings would follow from that. b could map to a' or d'.

Comment: Ah, okay. Yes, you can think about it that way for sure. You are now good to go!

Comment: okay,  thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Consider an arbitrary isomorphism, $G'$, of $G$, and its corresponding bijection, $f$. We must preserve the adjacency and non adjacency of $G$.

Let us start (without loss of generalization) with $a$, which we will map to an arbitrary vertex of degree 2 in $G'$. We have 4 choices possible. Notice that no matter which vertex you pick, its neighbors will be $v$, a vertex of degree 2, and $w$, a vertex of degree 3. Since we **must** preserve the adjacency and non adjacency of $G$, it follows that the vertex of degree 3 must be labelled $b$, and the vertex of degree 2 must be labelled $f$.

It should be very easy to complete the proof after this point, since our first choice forces every other vertex to be a certain label.

I hope this helped!